# Android: what happens with message queue when app goes background

Tags: android, message-queue

From my experience posted messages **are** delivered after app goes background. 
But is it **guarantied** :
**1)** that message will be delivered unless app was stopped and garbage collected?
**2)** that invocated code will be executed? Both on UI thread and background threads?

Is there something about it in official android documentation?

Thank

Comment: As long as the processing thread is running and free to handle the message queue, it will continue to be handled. That what the [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) is for.

Comment: AFAIK it is not guaranteed that an Activity will see anything other than onPause() before the process is killed. If you want to do something in background, you can use a Service (and it is much less likely that a process with a running service will be killed).